# calculate from how many days a values is repeated in the columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which contains many records. 
I should calculate the days elapsed from the presence of the numbers in columns with respect to the last date present in the column.

Example:

```
  id  |    data    | col1  | col2    | col3  |        
------+------------+-------+---------+-------+------
 3002 | 2019-07-27 | 13    | 33      | 40    |     
 3003 | 2019-07-30 | 6     | 8       | 28    |     
 3004 | 2019-08-01 | 20    | 12      | 37    |     
 3005 | 2019-08-03 | 6     | 16      | 21    |     
 3006 | 2019-08-06 | 20    | 22      | 1     |     
 3007 | 2019-08-08 | 6     | 10      | 24    |     
 3008 | 2019-08-10 | 10    | 15      | 42    |     
 3009 | 2019-08-13 | 7     | 32      | 41    |     
 3010 | 2019-08-17 | 8     | 13      | 31    |     
 3011 | 2019-08-19 | 17    | 28      | 40    |      
 3012 | 2019-08-20 | 20    | 24      | 40    |     
 3013 | 2019-08-22 | 1     | 12      | 24    |     
 3014 | 2019-08-24 | 20    | 36      | 40    |     
(3014 rows)
```

Expectations:

the uniq_number column cannot contain an equal number.
the updated reference date is 2019-08-24.

```
  id  |    uniq_number    | days_elapsed  | lag_data  |        
------+------------+-------+---------+-------+------
1           20                   0          2019-08-24
2           36                   0          2019-08-24
3           40                   0          2019-08-24
4           1                    2          2019-08-22
5           12                   2          2019-08-22
6           24                   2          2019-08-22
7           17                   5          2019-08-19
8           28                   5          2019-08-19
9           8                    7          2019-08-17
etc..
```

the numbers of the columns of the row with id 3012 have already come out in the id 3013 and 3014 so they will be excluded

in essence it is a matter of calculating the most lagging numbers.

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand this. Can you have another go at explaining your thought process as to why you rejected 3013 and 3014? For example is it because 3013's col3 is 24 and this appeared in col2 for 3012? Why did you keep 3012 when it has 20 that appears in 3004?

Comment: Do you want to add up col1+col2+col3 and have this be unique, by rejecting other later/earlier(?) rows that sum to the same? In simple terms: sum col1+col2+col3, call it x. Keep only the latest row for any given value of x?

Comment: Please write your SQL code, what you try to do

Comment: I was wrong to write the day elapsed. I corrected. the number 20 came out on 2019-08-24 so it has a day_elapsed of zero days. I will no longer need to calculate 20

Comment: it is fine to add the columns because two or more equal numbers will never appear in the same row

Comment: I'm mortified because I just can't think about it .. maybe with a little initial suggestion I can edit it and post it to optimize it

Comment: I guess you could do procedural code, iterate through unique number values (finding them all first if just going from minVal to maxVal seems unreasonable) and find `max(date) from table where col1=number or col2=numer or col3=number` and store those two in your expected format... don't know if there is a simpler way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can first use union the columns COL1, COL2, COL3 and then group the rows to achieve the result -

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MAX(data) DESC) id
      ,col1 uniq_number
      ,(SELECT MAX(data) FROM YOUR_TAB) - data days_elapsed
      ,data lag_data
FROM (SELECT MAX(data) data, col1
      FROM (SELECT data, col1
            FROM YOUR_TAB
            UNION
            SELECT data, col2
            FROM YOUR_TAB
            UNION
            SELECT data, col3
            FROM YOUR_TAB) T
     GROUP BY col1) temp
ORDER BY lag_data DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ERROR: syntax error at or near "data",... why? I use postgres

Comment: ok, I renamed the column name data ton data_ext and put UNION also in the other columns. it works perfectly. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you should union col1 , col2 ,col3 in one column with max date of each value then get diff date between max date of each of them and the most last date 
try this >>

```
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY MAXUN_COL DESC) id,
           uniq_number,
           DATEDIFF (day, MAXUN_COL, (SELECT max (date) FROM YOUR_TABLE)) days_elapsed  ,
           MAXUN_COL lag_data
      FROM (SELECT max (union_col.D) MAXUN_COL, union_col.uniq_number uniq_number
              FROM (SELECT Date D, col1 uniq_number FROM YOUR_TABLE
                    UNION 
                    SELECT Date, col2 FROM YOUR_TABLE
                    UNION 
                    SELECT Date, col3 FROM YOUR_TABLE) union_col
            GROUP BY uniq_number) d_T
```